# Python: Changing datatype of variable

Tags: c++, python, c

I'm new to Python and I'm finding this weird (and amazing). Can someone explain?

```
a = 2.0
b = 3.1
if b==3.1:
    print "%f"%a
    a = "Hi!"
    print "%s"%a
print "%s"%a


Output:
2.000000
Hi!
Hi!
```

How is the type of `a` changing from `float` to `string`?
How can something similar be done in C/C++ ?

Comment: python is dynamically typed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing

Comment: This can't be done in C/C++, because they are statically typed language, whereas, Python is dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is a [**dynamically typed**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamically_typed#Dynamic_typing) language, meaning that the same variables can refer to objects of different types.  Languages like C, C++ and Java are [statically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamically_typed#Static_typing), meaning that types are determined at compile time.

In statically typed languages which support object-oriented programming, like C++, you can use inheritance and polymorphism (base class pointers) to refer to multiple objects of different sub-class types, but it is not as flexible as the "[duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)" you get in Python.

In C and C++ you can also use generic `void*` pointers to point to an object of any type, but you lose the [type-safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Python is dynamically typed.  There are no type declarations, and any name can refer to any value at any time.

Statically typed languages like C and Java assign types to variables, and it is an error to assign values of the wrong type to a name.  Python has no such restriction.